# A good stratification of a variety on which an algebraic group acts

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, algebraic-groups, invariant-theory, geometric-invariant-theory

Let $X$ be an algebraic variety over an algebraically closed field $k$ of characteristic 0
(a reduced separated scheme of finite type over $k$).
Let $G$ be a connected linear algebraic group over $k$ (an connected affine group scheme of finite type over $k$) acting on $X$.

I am looking for a ***proof or a reference to a proof*** of the following lemma:

> **Lemma.** There exists a stratification
> $$ X=\bigsqcup_{i\in I} X_i $$
> of $X$ into a finite union of $G$-invariant non-intersecting locally closed subvarieties $X_i$ with the following properties:

(1) Each $X_i$ is irreducible and  smooth.

(2) For each $i$ there exists a surjective morphism $f_i\colon X_i\to Y_i$  onto a *smooth* $k$-variety $Y_i$ whose fibres are orbits of $G$ in $X_i$.

(3) Each morphism $f_i$ is flat, or, equivalently, all orbits of $G$ in $X_i$ have the same dimension $n_i$ depending only on $i$.

**EDIT.** What else can be required for a stratification to be *good*?

Comment: Do you want the $f_i$ in (2) to be $G$-equivariant?

Comment: @LSpice:  The group $G$ does not act on $Y_i$ because the fibres of $f_i$ are orbits of $G$.